# Multithreading and gtk2hs

Tags: multithreading, haskell, gtk, reactive-banana

I'm writing some code with reactive-banana and gtk2hs that needs to read from a file handle. I need to have at least two threads (one to read keyboard events with reactive banana and one to read from the file handle), so at the moment I have code that looks something like this:

```
type EventSource a = (AddHandler a, a -> IO ())

fire :: EventSource a -> a -> IO ()
fire = snd

watch :: EventSource ByteString -> Handle -> IO ()
watch textIn pty = forever $
  hGetLine pty >>= fire textIn >> threadWaitRead pty
```

With the following main function:

```
mainAxn :: IO ()
mainAxn = do
  h <- openFile "foo" ReadMode

  initGUI

  win <- windowNew
  txt <- textViewNew

  containerAdd win txt

  widgetShowAll win

  (keyPress, textIn) <-
    (,) <$> newAddHandler <*> newAddHandler
  network <- setupNetwork keyPress textIn
  actuate network

  _ <- forkIO $ watch textIn h

  _ <- win `on` keyPressEvent $
       eventKeyVal >>= liftIO . fire keyPress >> return True

  mainGUI
```

and my event network set up as follows:

```
setupNetwork :: EventSource KeyVal -> EventSource ByteString -> IO EventNetwork
setupNetwork keyPress textIn = compile $ do
  ePressed <- fromAddHandler $ addHandler keyPress
  eText <- fromAddHandler $ addHandler textIn

  reactimate $ print <$> (filterJust $ keyToChar <$> ePressed)
  reactimate $ print <$> eText
```

(except in my actual code, those `reactimate` calls write to the `TextView` built in `mainAxn`). I found that I needed to build with `-threaded` to make the event network correctly capture both text from `textIn` and keypresses from `keyPress`, which caused issues because it's not safe to modify objects from the gtk package concurrently.

At the moment, I have `postGUIAsync` calls scattered throughout my code, and I've found that using `postGUISync` causes the whole thing to deadlock --- I'm not sure why. I think it's because I end up calling `postGUISync` inside of the same thread that ran `mainGUI`.

It seems like it would be better to run all of the GUI stuff in its own thread and use the `postGUI*` functions for every access to it. However, when I change the last line of `mainAxn` to be

```
forkIO mainGUI
return ()
```

the program returns immediately when it hits the end of `mainAxn`. I tried to fix that by using:

```
forkIO mainGUI 
forever $ return ()
```

but then the gtk GUI never opens at all, and I don't understand why.

What's the right way to do this? What am I missing?

Comment: `forever $ return ()` is a bad idea -- wait for the `mainGUI` thread to finish instead. e.g. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threads-0.5.1.3/docs/Control-Concurrent-Thread.html

Comment: Also, you should use `forkOS mainGUI`. See [my discussion of multithreading in gtk2hs](http://dmwit.com/gtk2hs) for why.

Comment: (Author of reactive-banana here.) I think the issue is independent of reactive-banana. It seems to me that you need `-threaded` in order for `threadWaitRead` to be run concurrently with with the GTK GUI; not entirely sure though.

Comment: @HeinrichApfelmus Yes, it's pretty independent of reactive-banana, I just included the info to better explain my use case. Also, this is my second reactive-banana question you've answered personally -- thanks for being so active!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem here is that, in Haskell, as soon as `main` exits, the entire program is torn down. The solution is simply to keep the `main` thread open; e.g.

```
done <- newEmptyMVar
forkOS (mainGUI >> putMVar done ())
takeMVar done
```

I've also replaced `forkIO` with `forkOS`. GTK uses (OS-)thread-local state on Windows, so as a matter of defensive programming it is best to ensure that `mainGUI` runs on a bound thread just in case one day you want to support Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Wagner answered my question as asked, but I got a more informative perspective from the #haskell IRC channel, which I'll post here for future reference.

Rather than jumping through awkward hoops of forking off the GUI thread and putting the main thread to sleep, a better solution is to let the main thread be the GUI thread and deal with the reactive-banana event network in a new thread. I ended up modifying my `main` function to contain the following:

```
keyChan <- newChan
_ <- forkIO $ watchKeys keyPress keyChan
_ <- win `on` keyPressEvent $
    eventKeyVal >>= liftIO . writeChan keyChan >> return True
```

where `watchKeys` is defined as:

```
watchKeys :: EventSource KeyVal -> Chan KeyVal -> IO ()
watchKeys keyPress chan = forever $
    readChan chan >>= fire keyPress
```

Now I can deal with the `postGUI(A)Sync` issues in exactly one place, by defining:

```
reactimateSafe :: Frameworks t => Event t (IO ()) -> Moment t ()
reactimateSafe = reactimate . fmap postGUIAsync
```

and using `reactimateSafe` for any IO action that modifies a GTK object